# MSBOT-LUIS: How to specify the mandatory words in utterance? Is it possible by using phrase list features?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using phrase list features of LUIS. i am adding my mandatory words in my phrase list.(correct me if i am wrong)
For single mandatory word my intent works fine. But in my another intent i have 2 mandatory words in single intent which is not working fine.

## Behaviour

My phrase list- product: [moisturizer,anti wrinkle cream,laugh lines,anti aging skin treatment]
target area: [face,my face,neck,forehead]
Intent name- ste1
utterance- do you have moisturizer?
user enters- "do you have bla bla"- as expected its going to none intent.
Intent name- ste2
utterance- do you have moisturizer for my face?
user input- "do you have moisturizer for my bla bla"- As here "moisturizer" is present bt "my face" is not! This should also hit none intent but its hitting to ste1 intent because "do you have moisturizer?" is completely present in ste1.

## Expected Result-

I want to validate that my these two words(moisturizer, face) should be mandate to hit the ste2 intent otherwise i want it to hit none intent.

Comment: you add those utterances in None intent. Also, add attributes for the correct ones if you haven't added.

Comment: But user can enter any random thing so I cant predict what should be in none intent... that is the reason I want specific words as an input..

Comment: do you've atrributes set? Also you need to train with wrong utterances in None intent. Else, you won't get the desired result.

Comment: yes I have luis attribute intents.. such as for my products- moisturizer, toner, cleanser. I have created **product category** as entity and added list of products in it.

Comment: @Raviteja I tried adding wrong utterances in none intent.. but still as my partial utterance is correct its not hitting to none intent

Answer (score 0):

LUIS only provides a recognition service. If you want to validate something like `"face"` and `"moisturizer"` being present in a user's utterance, this should be done in your code.

You may train your bot to direct "incomplete" utterances to the `"None"` intent (by your description, utterances like, `"I want moisturizer"`, or `"I want lotion"`) but as you yourself noted;

> *But user can enter any random thing so I cant predict what should be in none intent...*

Therefore what you should do in your model and code is add entities for "moisturizer" and "face". With these entities, inside of your code you can take the LUIS response and quickly see if you have the required basic information to start the dialog. If one entity is provided (`"moisturizer"`) but another entity is missing (a part of the body), your bot would help the user disambiguate by prompting them what they're looking for specifically, e.g. *face* moisturizer or *hand* moisturizer.

A good way to approach the phrase lists and pattern features is that they're *augmentations*; they do help the machine learned model, but the weight/impact they provide when determining an intent is *less* than an entity's weight. The phrase lists and pattern features are not replacements for entities.

Comment: Hi Steven, Thanks for your response. Can you please help me out with some code examples of how I can validate these things.

Comment: I'm not as proficient with the .NET SDK, but perhaps this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/intelligence-LUIS/) may help. Here is the [LuisResult reference](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dc/dbe/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_luis_1_1_models_1_1_luis_result.html#ae3a440cb04289d7ef653e70103bc1e32). This last link may be the most helpful if you're using FormFlow; you can set [initial values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-advanced) before starting the form.